# How can I concisely duplicate an ActiveRecord object and change an attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Can this be done in fewer lines?

```
clone = self.dup
clone.assign_attributes owner: owner
clone.save
```

Even two lines would be better than three!

Comment: Please read "[ask]" and its links. We'd like to see a more indicative title, along with a description of the problem and what you're trying to accomplish. SO isn't just about answering your question, it has a long-term goal of answering similar questions for people looking for a solution in the future. So, write the question for them, not just for yourself. Also, if your code works, then [codereview.se] is potentially a better site than Stack Overflow.

Comment: @theTinMan Thanks! I didn't know about Code Review, I'll definitely try it. Regarding the question, I'd love to have a better title but couldn't come up with one, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Don't ask this question on Code Review. It's too generic, and would be downvoted or closed.

Comment: A better title suggestion: How can I concisely duplicate an ActiveRecord object and change an attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know Rails but I assume this would work:

```
dup.tap { |clone| clone.assign_attributes(owner: owner) }.save
```

Answer (score 3):

```
self.class.create(attributes.merge(owner: owner))
```

Comment: Right on the money. I'd even say `create!` is better since it will make a lot of noise if there's problems.

Comment: Awesome! But where is `attributes` defined?

Comment: `attributes` is defined in [ActiveRecord::Attributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods.html#method-i-attributes) which is included in `ActiveRecord::Base`